# How to find label with some name using cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to check the element next to the *label* `username` to be a *span* with text `certificate uploaded`

below is the html

```
<div class="square">
    <label>username</label>
    <span>cerfiticate uploaded</span>
</div>
```

Could someone help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`cy.contains()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains) like this:

```
cy.contains('span', 'cerfiticate uploaded');
```

Or use it with [`cy.next()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/next)  If you want to chain the *span* with *label*:

```
cy.contains('label', 'username')
.next()
// or
//.next('span')
.should('have.text', 'cerfiticate uploaded');
```

*For the original question:*

You can use [`cy.get()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Selector) like this:

```
cy.get('input[placeholder="something"]')
.should('be.disabled');
```

Comment: sorry but i have changed the question

Comment: thanks but is it possible to chain the span with label username.

Comment: yes, you could use [`.next()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/next#Syntax), check my update